# Naughts and crosses in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Been given this task from school, I am very new to programming. This is what I have done so far. The program starts up fine, but when I click a cell it does what I want but errors come up and I feel like I'm doing it wrong. Please bare in mind that the program is not finished.

The aim of the program is to create a Tic Tac Toe game using the given HTML. This has to be made from just JS. The task is write a progeram that places an X onto whatever cell the user clicks, with 2 different players.

I think the problem is when I call the functions.

I can't edit the HTML.

If anyone could help a brother out I would appreciate it a lot.

```js
var table = ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"];
var player = 1;

function ex(choice) 
{
  if (player == 1) 
  {
    table[choice - 1] = "X";
    player = 0;
  } 
  else 
  {
    table[choice - 1] = "O";
    player = 1;
  }
  console.log(player + " is playing");
  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) 
  {
    document.getElementById("cell" + i).innerHTML = table[i - 1];
  }
}

document.getElementById("cell" + 1).onclick = ex(1);
document.getElementById("cell" + 2).onclick = ex(2);
document.getElementById("cell" + 3).onclick = ex(3);
document.getElementById("cell" + 4).onclick = ex(4);
document.getElementById("cell" + 5).onclick = ex(5);
document.getElementById("cell" + 6).onclick = ex(6);
document.getElementById("cell" + 7).onclick = ex(7);
document.getElementById("cell" + 8).onclick = ex(8);
document.getElementById("cell" + 9).onclick = ex(9);

//for (var count = 1; count < 10; count++)        
//{                                  
//  document.getElementById("cell" + count).onclick = ex(count);
//}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="5" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell1">-</td>
      <td id="cell2">-</td>
      <td id="cell3">-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell4">-</td>
      <td id="cell5">-</td>
      <td id="cell6">-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell7">-</td>
      <td id="cell8">-</td>
      <td id="cell9">-</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Errors:

Error detected during event: 'call' on 'undefined' is not a function
Error at or around line number 24

Any cell I click this error shows with its particular line of code

Comment: What errors you are getting?

Comment: please help us to help you and add descriptions of the desired and current behavior in detail

Comment: Sorry, just added the errors I get

Comment: Use the debugger. Press F12 to get the debugger.

Comment: I have updated the post.

Comment: There aren't actually any errors that come up when running your snippet. The only problem is that all the cells are prefilled. And this is because you're passing the *result* of the function calls as the `onclick` attributes, not the functions themselves. So instead of `ex(1)` you need (using an arrow function because it's quicker to type, and works in all reasonably modern browsers) `() => ex(1)`. (A couple of other points: using `addEventListener` is much better than `onclick` - and you should be looking for a way to avoid typing almost the same line of code 9 times.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that when you set the `onclick` property of all your cells, you actually calling the function, thus running the code within it. You don't want this to happen as you only want it to do this when you click on a cell. So what you can do is wrap your function call within another function. This allows you to click the `onclick` button so it will then call the function within the function (allowing you to pass arguments into your `ex` function). This will solve your issue with the code you currently have, however, if you wish to dynamically create elements you can use the `for` loop at the bottom of your code.

However, there is a small issue with this for-loop. You need to change `var` to `let` in

`for(var count = 1; ...)`

the reason as to why is because `var` will make it so all your function calls have the same value of `choice` which is 10 - the last value of `count`, whereas you instead want to have incrementing values `1, 2, 3 etc...`. Fixing this will resolve your issue.

See working example below:

```js
var table = ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"];
var player = 1;

function ex(choice) {
  console.log(choice);
  if (player == 1) {
    table[choice - 1] = "X";
    player = 0;
  } else {
    table[choice - 1] = "O";
    player = 1;
  }
  console.log(player + " is playing");
  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    document.getElementById("cell" + i).innerHTML = table[i - 1];
  }
}


for (let count = 1; count < 10; count++) {
  document.getElementById("cell" + count).onclick = function() {
    ex(count)
  };
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="5" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell1">-</td>
      <td id="cell2">-</td>
      <td id="cell3">-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell4">-</td>
      <td id="cell5">-</td>
      <td id="cell6">-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell7">-</td>
      <td id="cell8">-</td>
      <td id="cell9">-</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you

Comment: @Shayrapet No worries, hope you learnt something new